# Batch delete files that aren't specified

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch file to quickly delete all files in a specific folder (I have quite a few documents in many locations). I am trying to delete every file, except for the batch file that I am running it from. I am trying to use an IF NOT statement, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my IF statement:

```
if not "%%a" == *Delete.bat" (
```

Where %%a is the file that I am currently testing whether or not to delete it. I'm rather sure that the error is coming from the "%%a": part of the statement, however I cannot confirm this.

**Note:**
When I run the file, it deletes everything including itself.

Comment: Just at a glance, you've got a `*` where a `"` should be.

Comment: I know. This is to allow anything before the "Delete" in the name.

Comment: You say that you're *rather sure that the error* is coming from something, but you've failed to include information on any error. What *error* are you getting?

Comment: As I stated in the Note, the error is that it will delete everything in that folder, rather than everything except for the file itself.

Comment: Um, no. That's not an error. That's behavior you don't want. There's a difference.

Comment: Have you tried using `if not "%%a" == "*Delete.bat" (`

Comment: You need to put the opening quote at the `"*Delete.bat"` part; and you should state the `/I` switch (`if /I not`) as you are comparing file names which are case-**in**sensitive in Windows...

Comment: `if /I "%%a" neq "%~NX0" del "%%a"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` can't work with wildcards. So as long as your batchfile doesn't start with a literal asterisk (unlikely, as `*` is not a valid character for a filename), this won't work.

Aacinis comment shows you the way to go:

```
if /I "%%a" neq "%~NX0" del "%%a"
```

`"%~NX0"` evaluates the **N**ame and e**X**tension of your batchfile

Comment: This still deletes all the files including my batch file.

Comment: you can't expect an answer be much better than the question. We had to guess, how your `for` works and therefore what `%%a` would be. You might have to change `"%~NX0"` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

it is true that if statements cant use wildcards.
to do what you want, place the wildcard in the for loop and not in the if-statement

```
:: to navigate to the directory of the file
Cd "%~dp0"
for /f %%a in (*.*) do (
   if not "%%a" == "delete.bat" (
       del "%%a"
))
```

that will do it